# Unlimited ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list

I need to make trivial array of strings in Java but I can not find a simple way to do it. I try to use `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();` but implementation says this is limited to 10 items. The question is simple how to make array of strings without limit which is able to add new items and iterate in for cycle around it.

Comment: ArrayList is **not** limited to 10 items.  You can put an arbitrary number of items into the list.  Where did you see this claim that it has a limit of 10?  **Edit:**, Ah, I bet you saw the initial capacity.  That's just the starting capacity.  When you add an 11th item, the list will auto expand to a larger capacity.

Comment: ArrayList will auto-expand itself when it reaches its limit. You can have as many as you can fit in memory. You may want to pre-allocate the array by giving it an int parameter. e.g. `new ArrayList<>(10000)` for a list of size 10000.

Comment: "but implementation says this is limited to 10 items" - *where* did you read that?

Comment: It's likely a bit of confusing documentation. The default allocation is 10, but that's not the limit.

Comment: I read this in IDE: Constructs an empty list with an initial capacity of ten. So I though it is the limit. I am new in Java so excuse me. My bad.

Comment: @Čamo the keyword here is *"initial"*

Answer (score 1):

From the [API Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically

An `ArrayList` is just some methods wrapped around an array. That 'backing' array does have a capacity; the default is 10 as you mentioned. An `ArrayList` instance automatically replaces the backing array with a larger one as needed.

Comment: ArrayList can't hold more than Integer.MAX_VALUE values